# Sort array into 3 buckets depending on numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, java-8

Given a collection of numbers, I'm trying to sort it into 3 different buckets equally to see how the numbers are relative to one another.

This is the solution I came up with, but I was wondering if there's any case this may fail (positive numbers though). Also, is there a better way for me to do this/improve/look cleaner.

```
    Set<Long> values = api.GetValues();

    Set<Long> lowBucket = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Long> midBucket = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Long> highBucket = new HashSet<>();

    Long min = Collections.min(values);
    Long max = Collections.max(values);

    double lowThreshold = (max - min)/3;
    double midThreshold = lowThreshold*2;

    for(Long i : values){
        if(i < lowThreshold){
            lowBucket.add(i);
        }else if(i >= lowThreshold && i < midThreshold){
            midBucket.add(i);
        }else{
            highBucket.add(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: test your code for next set `1, 100000, 100001`

Comment: You are assuming that the numbers are evenly spaced (i.e. that `(max - min)/3` represents an exact threshold). A better way would be to sort the list and divide it in 3.

Comment: @Maljam Sorting is an overkill (in terms of time complexity), it can be done in linear time.

Comment: @amit really? How could you for example find the median of non-sorted data in linear time? Because it's the same conceptual problem.

Comment: @Maljam Like my answer says, by using [Selection Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm). The tl;dr of it is basically, do a quicksort step, and now you know what the index of the current pivot is, you know if the median is to its left or right, and recurse only on one subarray. This causes O(n) time.

Comment: @Holger It's a shame you argue before you read more about the mentioned algorithm. Since the algorithm needs to recurse on half of the array, its next iteration has (on average) half of the current elements. The complexity function describing this algorithm is `T(n) = T(n/2) + O(n)` (this is a simplification because it's average case, but the "real" analysis is close to it). From [master theorem case 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Case_3) `T(n)` is in `Theta(n)` (Or if you prefer: `n+n/2+n/4+n/8 + .... < 2n`, and again `T(n)` is in `O(n)`)

Comment: @Holger And if you concern about worst case performance, [Median Of Medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) gurantees worst case `O(n)` complexity for selection.

Comment: @amit: since this is about practical solutions, having `O(n)` in the average case is fine and I admit, I was a bit too fast with my comment. But consider that the performance of a sort operation isn’t that bad (the Collections API uses TimSort, not quicksort) in the average case either and the simplicity of a “sort and make three chunks” solution therefore has a point.

Comment: @Holger I explicitly mentioned it's an overkill in terms of **time complexity**, for quick coding solution, yes, sorting is probably faster to code. Regarding which is better and when: Since the selection algorithm needs on average `2n` element reads, and since constants between quickselect and quick sort are pretty similar, we can actually calculate a good estimation for it. We need two selections, and an additional one pass to split into buckets, so we need `5` traversals. quicksort needs ~log_2(n) traversals, so we should prefer selection when `5 < log_2(n) -> n > 32` as rough approximation

Comment: @amit: as said, Quicksort isn’t used by the Collection API so it doesn’t help to estimate what Quicksort would do.

Comment: @Holger For the fun of it, I implemented both and benchmarked them, and ran wilcoxon statistical test for statistical proof of the results. The results are: at ~100 elements; the algorithms are equivalent. For ~150+ elements, the selection method is superior. For smaller arrays, sorting is superior. Note that I did not do any optimizations for my quickselect (like inlining swap() and partition(),...) which could make the selection algorithm even better. Full experiment code is on [ideone](http://ideone.com/1cFp9C). (and added to my answer).

Comment: See a [JMH benchmark](https://github.com/kedarmhaswade/jmh-benchmarks/blob/master/median-finding-benchmark.md) about this which suggests that QuickSelect is twice as fast as the naive `Arrays.sort` based solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for [order statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic)s. These can be found efficiently using [Selection Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm).

Once you found the order statistic of the 1/3'th element and 2/3'th element, it's pretty simply to split the elements into the buckets.

---

For the fun of it, I implemented both sorting and selection algorithms, and compared them.

For relatively small arrays (smaller than ~100), sorting is superior. For larger arrays, selection algorithm is superior. The results are statistical significant according to [wilcoxon test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test).

Code available at [ideOne](http://ideone.com/1cFp9C) (and appendix of this answer)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    // experiment variables:
    public static final int NUM_ELEMENTS = 150;
    public static final int NUM_WARMUP_ROUNDS = 100000;
    public static final int NUM_EXPERIMENTS = 200;
    // aux variables:
    private static Random rand = new Random();
    private static List<Integer> list;

    // selection method implementation:
    private static void swap(int[] arr, int idx1, int idx2) { 
        int temp = arr[idx1];
        arr[idx1] = arr[idx2];
        arr[idx2] = temp;
    }
    private static int partition(int[] arr, int left, int right) { 
        int pivotIdx = left + rand.nextInt(right-left);
        swap(arr, pivotIdx, right - 1);
        right = pivotIdx = right-1;
        int pivot = arr[pivotIdx];
        while (left < right) { 
            while (arr[left] < pivot && left < right) left++;
            while (arr[right] >= pivot && right > left) right--;
            if (left >= right) break;
            swap(arr, left, right);
        }
        // now, left is the first element bigger than pivot.
        swap(arr, pivotIdx, left);
        return left;
    }

    public static int quickSelect(int[] arr, int n) { 
        return quickSelect(arr, n, 0, arr.length);
    }

    private static int quickSelect(int[] arr, int n, int l, int r) { 
        int p = partition(arr, l, r);
        if (n == p) return arr[p];
        if (n < p) return quickSelect(arr, n, l, p + 1);
        return quickSelect(arr, n, p, r);
    }

    // we are assuming arr.length % 3 == 0 for simplicty;
    public static int[][] getThreeBucketsSelection(int[] arr) { 
        int[] first_bucket = new int[arr.length / 3];
        int i1 = 0;
        int[] second_bucket = new int[arr.length / 3];
        int i2 = 0;
        int[] third_bucket = new int[arr.length / 3];
        int i3 = 0;
        int p1 = quickSelect(arr, arr.length / 3);
        int p2= quickSelect(arr, (arr.length / 3) * 2);
        for (int x : arr) { 
            if (x < p1) first_bucket[i1++] = x;
            else if (x < p2) second_bucket[i2++] = x;
            else third_bucket[i3++] = x;
        }
        return new int[][] {first_bucket, second_bucket, third_bucket};
    }

    // sorting implementation:
    public static int[][] getThreeBucketsSort(int[] arr) { 
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        int[] first_bucket = new int[arr.length / 3];
        int i1 = 0;
        int[] second_bucket = new int[arr.length / 3];
        int i2 = 0;
        int[] third_bucket = new int[arr.length / 3];
        int i3 = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < arr.length / 3) first_bucket[i1++] = arr[i++];
        while (i < 2 * arr.length / 3) second_bucket[i2++] = arr[i++];
        while (i < arr.length) third_bucket[i3++] = arr[i++];
        return new int[][] {first_bucket, second_bucket, third_bucket};     
    }

    // experiment methods:
    public static int[] createRandomPermutation() { 
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        int[] arr = new int[list.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (int x : list) arr[i++] = x;
        return arr;
    }

    public static List<Integer> populateOriginalList(int numElements) { 
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++)  result.add(i);
        return result;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        list = populateOriginalList(NUM_ELEMENTS);
        long sumWarmUpTime = 0; 
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_WARMUP_ROUNDS; i++) { 
            int[] arr1 = createRandomPermutation();
            int[] arr2 = Arrays.copyOf(arr1, arr1.length);
            long warmupIter = System.nanoTime();
            int[][] buckets1 = getThreeBucketsSelection(arr1);
            int[][] buckets2 = getThreeBucketsSort(arr2);
            sumWarmUpTime += System.nanoTime() - warmupIter;
        }

        System.out.println("Done warm up. Took: " + sumWarmUpTime + " nanos");
        List<Long> selectionTimes = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Long> sortTimes = new ArrayList<>();

        long quickSelectTotal = 0;
        long sortTotal = 0;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < NUM_EXPERIMENTS/2; i++) { 
            int[] arr1 = createRandomPermutation();
            int[] arr2 = Arrays.copyOf(arr1, arr1.length);
            // selection:
            long quickSelectTime = System.nanoTime();
            int[][] buckets1 = getThreeBucketsSelection(arr1);
            quickSelectTime = (System.nanoTime() - quickSelectTime);
            quickSelectTotal += quickSelectTime;
            selectionTimes.add(quickSelectTime);
            // sort:
            long sortTime = System.nanoTime();
            int[][] buckets2 = getThreeBucketsSort(arr2);           
            sortTime = (System.nanoTime() - sortTime);
            sortTotal += sortTime;
            sortTimes.add(sortTime);
        }

        // and flip their order, to make sure no bias:
        for (int i = 0 ; i < NUM_EXPERIMENTS/2; i++) { 
            int[] arr1 = createRandomPermutation();
            int[] arr2 = Arrays.copyOf(arr1, arr1.length);

            // sort:
            long sortTime = System.nanoTime();
            int[][] buckets1 = getThreeBucketsSort(arr1);           
            sortTime = (System.nanoTime() - sortTime);
            sortTotal += sortTime;
            sortTimes.add(sortTime);

            // selection:
            long quickSelectTime = System.nanoTime();
            int[][] buckets2 = getThreeBucketsSelection(arr2);
            quickSelectTime = (System.nanoTime() - quickSelectTime);
            quickSelectTotal += quickSelectTime;
            selectionTimes.add(quickSelectTime);            
        }       

        System.out.println("values for wilcoxon test");
        System.out.println("sort times: "  + sortTimes);
        System.out.println("selection times: "  + selectionTimes);

        System.out.println("Bottom lime results: ");
        System.out.println("sort: " + sortTotal);
        System.out.println("selection: " + quickSelectTotal);
    }
}/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */
```

Note: The above code is a simplification. Specifically, it does not handle dupe elements well, and assumes input array is a multiple of 3.

These both can be easily solved with very little performance penalty.

Comment: Note that the question has a `Set<Long>` as input and wants three `Set<Long>` as output, so when you sort a `Long[]` or `List<Long>`, the Collection API will use TimSort, whereas `Arrays.sort(int[])` will indeed use a QuickSort variant. Besides that, you should use `Arrays.copyOfRange` instead of rolling your own copy routine, especially as it makes some of your methods almost a one liner: `static int[][] getThreeBucketsSort(int[] arr) {Arrays.sort(arr);int l=arr.length;return new int[][] {Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, l/3),Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, l/3, 2*l/3),Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 2*l/3, l)};}`

Comment: Why does your `getThreeBucketsSelection` compare each element with the values returned by `quickSelect`? As far as I understood, `quickSelect` already does partitioning as upon return, the pivot is at the desired place and all elements before it are less than and all elements after it are greater than the pivot, so all you need to do is to copy the partition.

Comment: Note that this `quickSelect()` implementation returns the element, and not its index in the modified array. However, yes, this optimization can be done. Like I said, I did not spend time on optimizing it.

Comment: Well, we don’t need the index to be returned because the target index is given as input. So the return value can be ignored and the second invocation can be changed to `quickSelect(arr, (arr.length / 3) * 2, arr.length / 3, arr.length)` as the first partition doesn’t need to be touched. Then, the only step left is copying the three partitions, just like in the sort-based approach.

Comment: Yea, that makes sense. It does improve constants, and I assume it'll cause 10-20% faster execution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me, but you could simplify the check a bit:

```
    if(i < lowThreshold){
        lowBucket.add(i);
    }else if(i < midThreshold){
        midBucket.add(i);
    }else{
        highBucket.add(i);
    }
```